# How to establish connectivity in AWS EKS/Fargate hybrid mode (app on Fargate, db on EKS worker node)

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I'm running a hybrid version of EKS cluster where I'm trying to use AWS Fargate for some of my workload. From what I know, AWS Fargate can be used for stateless pods which makes natural that, for standard app/db scenario, you would have to use hybrid mode where app is running on Fargate while db is running on one of the EKS worker nodes.
Problem that I see is that app cannot communicate with db in this case.

Now, I would conclude that, workload on Fargate can be reached from the outside of the Fargate only if using ALB ingress in front?
If that is true, that would also not solve this problem since app (on Fargate) needs to connect to db (running on EKS worker nodes), not the vice versa. I guess this can be solved by having ALB ingress in front of db but seems to me like an overkill?

Is there any other way around this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need db running on EKS? If you really do, I think you can create a Cluster Service for your db pods so that your application pods can have access to it without too much effort.

On the other hand, I would just go with an instance of RDS and create a security group there to allow access from your EKS Fargate pods.